# How to render protected element?

Tags: entities

I want to print [entityInfo:protected] present in below image.

I am able to print all element except [entityInfo:protected] and [entityType:protected]

[image]

Comment: See: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/55075).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (without reflection). Protected members of a class are available only to the defining class and its subclasses - it's the whole point of using access modifiers in the first place - if you can get access to a protected value directly from the object, then the language has failed. Miserably.

If a method doesn't exist to expose that data already, you'll need to extend the class that represents that object to provide getter methods for the protected properties.

Comment: Thanks Clive. Once i have done this. I was getting a code written by you. But now i can not recall that. I am searching.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean I once gave you some code that could get around access modifier restrictions? Yes, please do find that, I want to see what it is :) The type of object you're dealing with, and what it inherits from, are important - is it an entity?

Comment: Yes i think you create a object to access.Yes it is a entity.I am using view with global php and try to render this.

Comment: You can extract bundle data with entity_get_keys, and use the entity_get_info to get metadata, could they be what you mean? Or perhaps an EntityMetadataWrapper?

Comment: yes you are right we can not access directly.